# How to calculate the Previous YTD for below mentioned table structure?

Tags: powerbi

I have three tables: Account Summary, DateTable(date table), Budget table.

I calculated the YTD for One of the measures by using below formula:
Total Retail Dues YTD = TOTALYTD([Total Retail Dues], DateTable[Date], "9/30")

For Prev YTD I am using below formula:
Total Retail Dues YTD LY = CALCULATE([Total Retail Dues YTD], SAMEPERIODLASTYEAR(DateTable[Date]))

However the Total Retail Dues YTD LY not showing the the YTD info, in turn it shows data for the whole fiscal year 2017. What to change for Previous YTD formula so that I can get YTD info for previous year not the whole fiscal year info?

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want the fiscal year correction in your LY calculation, you shouldn't reference the YTD for the fiscal year in your LY measure.

Could you try this?

```
Total Retail Dues YTD LY =
TOTALYTD([Total Retail Dues];SAMEPERIODLASTYEAR(DateTable[Date]))
```

For reference:

```
Total Retail Dues YTD - Fiscal Year = 
TOTALYTD([Total Retail Dues];DateTable[Date];"30/6")

Total Retail Dues YTD LY - Fiscal Year =
TOTALYTD([Total Retail Dues];SAMEPERIODLASTYEAR(DateTable[Date]);"30/6")

Total Retail Dues YTD = 
TOTALYTD([Total Retail Dues];DateTable[Date])

Total Retail Dues YTD LY =
TOTALYTD([Total Retail Dues];SAMEPERIODLASTYEAR(DateTable[Date]))
```

In picture:
[image]

Comment: HI TJ, thanks for your response. Below  is what I am looking to do: client has the fiscal year period runs from October 1st to September 30th, which is why I specified 9/30 to be considered as the end date. I am getting the right YTD info but when I do YTD LY it gives me the value for the whole fiscal year not the YTD. For e.g. I just want to show data from October 1st, 2016 to March 30th, 2017 for YTD LY but could not get it to work. It inturn gives me value for the period October 1st 2016 to September 30th, 2017 which is fiscal year 2017. I tried your DAX query but didn't work.

Comment: And my second reference? 
Total Retail Dues YTD LY - Fiscal Year =
TOTALYTD([Total Retail Dues];SAMEPERIODLASTYEAR(DateTable[Date]);"30/9")

Comment: HI TJ, that is not correct syntax wise. it prompts me with an error. we can't use semicolon in the DAX query.

Comment: Please replace semicolon with a comma, due to my locale I have a different setting.

Comment: Unfortunately it still shows me data for the fiscal year 2017 not the YTD info.

Comment: That's strange.. could you post a screenshot or pbix file? Question; the sample in the image I posted; does that looks ok to you? The purple highlight?